# Grid 960 CSS question

Tags: css, 960.gs

When using the Grid 960 Framework in FF 3.6.14 OS X 10.5.8,

using CSS shorthand

```
margin: 50px 0 0 0;
```

cause the margins to shift down and left. All values must be long hand:

```
margin-top: 50px;
```

Has anyone encountered this,if so how and why does it occur?

Answer (score 1):

You're probably overriding a different CSS value, maybe `margin: x y z j` or sort.
It's better to override CSS with long hand elements, so, you're good.

Comment: Thanks again for the prompt attention!

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the fact it works on column system and it is centered within a certain width of 960px. When u add extra margins. It disrupts the floats etc because it is pushing the content out of the 960px area that is set.

You can go to the 960.gs site and then click generate css which will allow u to edit the margin and column sizes urself and redownload the template. Alternatively you could do it manually edit widths for individual divs but you may have to take away some margin/padding another element to make sure it does not excede the 960px for each row on your site